# FBX Animation can be preview in unity but cannot be imported into maya

Tags: unity-game-engine, maya

[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17jtDU5FANCNk5ykRkyBNYzNLLgT2b6YS/view?usp=sharing) is my fbx animation

it can be preview in unity editor
[image]

but in maya, when import it, not any animation keys

[image]

Comment: I use max so the interface might be similar. Try using the import menu fro File>Import , it should let you check options to include the animations on import. The first google search gives an answer: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-B423CAD7-6198-421F-B4BF-EC0EB3B580E1-htm.html

Answer (score 0):

thanks @comphonia, maya > file > import, in my case, import anim fbx only import model not animation keys

but when I use maya > windows > animation editors > time editor > file > import animation clip > and import anim fbx again, it work, it import animation keys

I don't know reason but it work

[image]